# Can I reduce the size of a chase, to more closely fit the ducts within it?

Tags: walls, studs, ducts, clearance

I have a framed in rectangle in my kitchen. I recently opened up a section of it and can see that there is only a 7" round duct in the roughly 22" x 30"box. I am wondering if I can possibly re frame the cavity to fit more closely to the duct so it won't be so bulky. I'm located in the Detroit area.

[image]

Comment: Is this duct operated by a fan to pull air to the outside?  As in a hood fan?  Everytime you reduce the duct size you wimp out the power of your system big time.  You want to keep the duct size the same!!  Is this for a vented hood over your stove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, assuming that 1) the cavity isn't actually in use as something else, say a return duct, and 2) you're sure you won't need to use it for utility access to other parts of your home in the future.

In fact, you may be able to move the duct entirely into the adjacent wall and eliminate the cavity altogether.